# Sonata Formatter Bundle generates an empty textarea

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use Ckeditor or markdown text editor in my admin panel of project

I have installed FormatterBundle , Ivory\CkeditorBundle, and Knp\MarkdownBundle in my project ....

in my PostAdmin.php

```
namespace Main\Bundle\MainBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class PostsAdmin extends Admin

/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('shortDescription')
        ->add('text', 'sonata_formatter_type', array(
            'source_field'         => 'text',
            'source_field_options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'span10', 'rows' => 20)),
            'format_field'         => 'text',
            'target_field'         => 'text',
            'ckeditor_context'     => 'default',
            'event_dispatcher'     => $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher()
        ))
        ->add('created')
        ->add('updated')
        ->with('Gallery')
            ->add('gallery', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'cascade_validation' => true,
                ), array(
                    'edit'              => 'inline',
                    'inline'            => 'table',
                    'sortable'          => 'position',
                    'link_parameters'   => array('context' => 'posts'),
                    'admin_code'        => 'sonata.media.admin.gallery'
                )
            )
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

my config.php is ..

```
sonata_formatter:
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig #keep this commented unless you are using media bundle.


        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        rawhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        richhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig


        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions

    ckeditor:
            templates:
                browser: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:browser.html.twig'
                upload: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:upload.html.twig'


ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            filebrowserBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser
            filebrowserImageBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser
            # Display images by default when clicking the image dialog browse button
            filebrowserImageBrowseRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
            filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_upload
            filebrowserUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.file
            # Upload file as image when sending a file from the image dialog
            filebrowserImageUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_upload
            filebrowserImageUploadRouteParameters:
                provider: sonata.media.provider.image
                context: posts # Optional, to upload in a custom context
```

Please give an advice why my textarea is an empty ??

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add

```
twig:
debug:            %kernel.debug%
strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

form:
    resources:
        # ...
        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

to your config file
(see http://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html)

Comment: Thank you , I haven't added this in config, thanks for advice